# How to prevent modal window from disappearing on screen lock on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, modal-dialog

I am a newbie in React Native, supporting a small Android app. During testing I have encountered a bug with modals that I am not able to solve.
Before I go back to developer with this bug, I would like to try and understand/fix it myself (with your help, of course).

Bug description: on specific action sequence the application UI freezes and do not respond to user interactions. At the same time Android hardware buttons work normally.

App is a basic bar-code scanner, sending GET requests to server and rendering responses.
If response data contains an error flag, a modal window with corresponding information and option buttons is displayed.

I was able to pinpoint the freezing occurrences to following behavior:
If warning modal is left active on screen until the screen locks (either by button press or by screen lock timer), on the further unlocking modal window is no longer visible on screen.

Despite modal is not visible, underlying view is non-responsive to scroll or tap, as if modal was still there. To get rid of it we need to restart the entire app.

Modal window code

```
// @flow
/* imports */

type Props = {
    warningText: ?string,
    options: ?string[],
    visible: boolean,
    onPress: (value: number) => void,
}

export default class WarningModal extends PureComponent<Props> {
    renderButtons = () => {
        /* code omitted */
    }

    render() {
        const { warningText, options, visible } = this.props
        return (
            <Modal
                visible={visible}
                fullScreen
                transparent
                onRequestClose={() => {}}
            >
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Title</Text>
                        <View>
                            <Text>{warningText}</Text>
                        </View>
                        {options && options.length > 0 ? this.renderButtons() : undefined}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

The only two places in app where showModal is set to false are in SceneComponent class as following:

1. in initialization of state variable:

```
state = {
        unitInfo: new Unit(),
        showModal: false,
    }
```

2. in method that handles option button press in modal window

```
onWarningPress = async (value: number) => {
        const {
            userStore: {
                state: {
                    user,
                },
            },
        } = this.props
        const { unitInfo } = this.state
        try {
            await saveWarning(value, user)
            this.setState({ showModal: false })
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.showAlert()
        }
    }
```

So far I couldn't find a solution for this issue, so I hope you can point me in the right direction, on how to avoid modal closing without user interaction. 
The desired behavior is that warning modal stays on screen indefinitely, until user presses an option button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a thorough investigation I am still not sure what is causing this issue. However, I have added a crude fix to my code to force Modal element to stay visible after screen lock/unlock.

Inspecting DOM tree of the app revealed that despite being literally invisible, Modal element is still present in the DOM tree with property `visible={true}`. Nevertheless, forcing re-render of SceneComponent with `this.forceUpdate()`, `this.setState(this.state)` or some dummy State key didn't have any effect.

So I went the ugly way of toggling showModal value to "false" and then back to "true" on app state change as following:

```
 componentDidMount() {
      AppState.addEventListener('change', this.toggleModal)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.toggleModal)
  }

  toggleModal = () => {   
       if (this.state.showModal === true) {
           this.setState({ showModal: false }) 
           this.setState({ showModal: true })
       }  
  }
```

This 'change' event fires on screen lock and next time screen is unlocked Modal is visible on screen, as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I was facing exact same issue and your fix worked for me too.

RN Modal sucks, still!

Answer (score 0):

The React Native `<Modal />` component is buggy. You can create your own modal component by applying [StyleSheet.absoluteFill](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#absolutefill) style to a `<View />` which wraps your modal content.